# const declaration inside the class

Tags: c++

> to avoid complicated linker rules, C++ requires that every object has
>   a unique definition. That rule would be broken if C++ allowed in-class
>   definition of entities that needed to be stored in memory as objects.

I'm having hard time understanding this:

```
class Y {
    const int c3 = 7;       // error: not static
    static int c4 = 7;      // error: not const
    static const float c5 = 7;  // error: not integral
    static const int c6 = 7;

};
```

How does `const int c6 = 7;` break  following rule?

> C++ requires that every object has
>    a unique definition.

And `static const int c6 = 7;` do not break it (enums too)?

Please also explain why `static const float c5 = 7;` is not allowed but `static const int c5 = 7;` is allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of these rules have been changing over time, so it really depends on the version of C++ you are using. Also, some of these may not be technically impossible, but the committee simply decided against them because they might be hard to implement, or are prone to errors. So you might not always get the most satisfying answer on why thing are the way they are.

Lets go over them one by one.

**Const Member**

```
class Foo
{
    const int bar = 7;
};
```

This used to be illegal before C++11. Before that version you were only allowed to initialize static variables in their declaration. If you are still not on C++11, my condolences. More details can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).

**Static Member**

```
class Foo
{
    static int bar = 7;
};
```

Another one that changed, but more recently. Before C++17 it was illegal to initialize non const static variables in their declaration. This has to do with the one definition rule. When the header containing this class is included in multiple translation units (.cpp files), which one should be responsible for initializing the value? This is why you have to place the definition somewhere in a single .cpp file.

After C++17 you are allowed to do this:

```
class Foo
{
    inline static int bar = 7;
};
```

When you use inline like this it somehow figures out how to only initialize it once. More details can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Static_data_members).

**Static Const Float Member**

```
class Foo
{
    static const float bar = 7.0f;
};
```

This has mainly to do with the unpredictability of floats when you run into floating point errors. An example:

```
class Foo
{
    static const float bar = 0.1f;
};
```

Since 0.1f is impossible to represent in most floating point implementations, you won't get exactly 0.1f, but only something very close to it. This can then result in different behaviors on different systems that have slightly different implementations, causing your program to run differently depending on the system.

This gets even worse when the value is the result of a calculation, because `(a*b)*c` is not guaranteed to be the exact same value as `a*(b*c)`, even though it might seem like they are.

But const static floats are still allowed when you define the value outside of the class, so technically it would all still be possible to implement. But the committee never did, probably because it would cause more problems than it would solve. This is also similar to why you are allowed to use integral types as template parameters, but not floats.

```
template <int i> class Foo {}; // Good
template <float f> class Bar {}; // Bad
```

However, the committee seems to have changed it's opinion somewhat, since we are now allowed to use floats with `constexpr`. So it can be done if you write this instead:

```
class Foo
{
    static constexpr float bar = 7.0f;
};
```

**Conclusion**

All of these are actually possible in some form with the right version of C++ and the right syntax. Just keep in mind the potential issues described above, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Actually, `0.1f` _is_ possible to represent (it's a C++ literal after all) — it just won't be equal to one tenth in the radix-2 floating-point implementations. Anyway, this doesn't really explain why you still can have `struct Foo { static const float bar; }; const float Foo::bar=0.1f;` even in C++03, where it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Let go through it.

```
FIRST READ BELOW THEN COME TO CODE
class Y {
    const int c3 = 7;       // It's fine. If you write good constructor.
//    static int c4 = 7;      // error: not const as it is trying to initialize with object constructor which it shouldn't 
    static const float c5 = 7;  // error: not integral as we can do it for integral type only. To correct this you can do.
     static constexpr float c5 = 7; // we should use constexpr for literal type.
   static const int c6 = 7; // it was fine   as both types are same int and 6 where it was not the case in 1st case.
};
int main()
{
    Y y;
}
```

First, learn these lines

a. When we create a const object of a class type, the object does not
assume its `constness` until after the constructor completes the object's initialization.
Thus, constructors can write to const objects during their construction.
So this will yield an error.

```
class Const {
public:
Const(int ii);
private:
int i;
const int ci;
};
ConstRef::ConstRef(int ii)
{ // assignments:
i = ii; // ok
ci = ii; // error: cannot assign to a const
}
**TO CORRECT THIS YOU SOULD DO**
Const::Const(int ii): i(ii), ci(ii) { } // this is how constructor should be
```

Let's discuss everything one by one.

1. Your fist member is already excellent. It should work fine as per my knowledge, and it's working for me. I think it's not working for you because your constructor is trying to initialize it in the constructor body, which you can't.

   > We must use the constructor initializer list to provide values for members that
   >   are const, reference, or of a class type that does not have a default
   >   constructor.
2. Let come to the static part

   > We say a member is associated with the class by adding the keyword static to its declaration.
   >   The static members of a class exist outside any object.
   >   static member functions are not bound to any object; they do not have
   >   a this pointer. As a result, static member* functions*  may not be declared as const, and we may not refer to this in the body of a static member. This restriction applies both to explicit uses of this and to implicit uses of this by calling
   >   a nonstatic member.

**IMP**

> Because static data members are not part of individual objects of the class type, they are not defined when we create objects of the class. As a result, they are not initialized by the class’ constructors. Moreover, in general, we may not initialize a static member inside the class. 
>   So i think you got your second error reason. You are trying to initialize it with object constructor.

Let's go to the third one.

> Ordinarily, class static members may not be initialized in the class body. However, **we can provide in-class initializers for static members that have const integral**
>   type and must do so for static members that are constexprs of literal type. The initializers must be constant expressions.
>   So.
>   `static constexpr float c = 7`; this is fine. You can check

I hope it' clear now. Let m know if you still got issues. Btw i skipped indirect concept too. But for depth understanding you need to learn about ``literal class`.